# C# won't run PowerShell script

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-sdk

I want to call PowerShell script from my C# project but it wont work.

When I run the code I don't get any errors(or I don't know where to find them). 
I also tried to run script from cmd and script works fine.

My execution policy is set to unrestricted so that is not a problem.

I double checked paths, so these are not problem either.

C# code:

```
string scriptPath = @"C:\Users\jmiha\Desktop\test.ps1";
var parameters = new List<String>();
parameters.Add("test");
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(scriptPath);
ps.AddParameters(parameters);
ps.Invoke();
```

PowerShell script:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$param
)
Add-Content 'c:\users\jmiha\desktop\test.txt' $param
```

When I open the test.txt it is empty.

Comment: `ps.AddScript(scriptPath);` --> `ps.AddCommand(scriptPath);`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Then what is the diff between them ?

Comment: @PrasoonKarunanV: `.AddScript()` is poorly named; `.AddScriptBlock()` would have made more sense: you pass it a self-contained snippet of PowerShell code - entire commands including their arguments; `.AddCommand()` adds a single command _name or path_ (including, if applicable, a script _file_), whose arguments must be added separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddScript` is meant for arbitrary code, not a command/parameter syntax.  You could use something like

```
ps.AddScript("Test-Path C:\temp").Invoke()
```

and it works.

If you want to bind parameters and the like, you need to use `AddCommand` which lets you interact with the commands like they objects they are and will bind your parameter:

```
using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    powershell
        .AddCommand(@"C:\Temp\test.ps1")
        .AddParameter("param", "TEST")
        .Invoke()
```

---

*p.s. the documentation of `System.Management.Automation.dll` is terrible.*

Comment: It solved the problem, thank you!!!